# Are these strtotime() formats exists?

Tags: php, mysql, date

Those are the usual `strtotime()` formats:

```
strtotime("now");
strtotime("3 October 2005");
strtotime("+5 hours");
strtotime("+1 week");
strtotime("+1 week 3 days 7 hours 5 seconds");
strtotime("next Monday");
strtotime("last Sunday");
```

etc.

I need a different format for my code,i have something like this:

```
$date = strtotime("6 Oct 2014"); 
$d=date('Y-M-j',$date);

$sql="CREATE DATABASE `".$row['Database'].".$d."`"; //this one creates a database with the current date,which is 6 Oct 2014
$query2=mysql_query($sql,$connect);
```

After a week,or two or a month,or a year i want to automatically drop that database,like this:

```
$sql="SHOW DATABASES LIKE '%".date('Y-M-j',strtotime("last ***",$date))."'"; 
 $query=mysql_query($sql,$connect);
  $sqlDROP="DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `".$row."`"; //this one will drop the listed databases above
     $queryDROP=mysql_query($sqlDROP,$connect);
```

What i want is a format instead of "last ***",that will drop the older database,i cant use formats like last month,last week,last year because i have many databases,made on different dates,and when i create a new one i need to drop the olders.

I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Please, please please, stop using the ***deprecated and unsafe*** `mysql_*` extension. Learn to use (And love) `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: as much as i would love to use those,i seriously can't ...

Comment: Well then, now is the time to learn. Just RTFM, `PDO` is _easy_. Invest some time (say, 2 hours) and you'll start to get the hang of it

Comment: @Elias I think, I *hope*, "can't" refers to some technical restriction rather than the OP's inability to learn...

Comment: @14k It's generally a pretty bad idea to create tables on the fly for individual days. Why in the world do you need that to begin with?!

Comment: @deceze: The only reason I can think of why OP can't use either one of the better extensions would be if the OP is still using PHP 4

Comment: @Elias Exactly. Something along those lines. There do exist dark spots of misery in this world... ;)

Comment: Are you sure this is an `strtotime()` problem? I'm having trouble understanding what exactly it is you need.

Comment: @Jack i tried to explain as good as i could.As a short preview,lets say today 18 9 2014 i create a database with name db-18-9-2014 , and in 3 months i create another database, db-18-9-2014 , in the drop query i need to find a way to introduce into the strtotime pattern a value like last time,so the older db will be deleted,this example,is just for 2 databases,but imagine i have a lot of db created this entire year,on different times.How can i drop them? without droping the one that im trying to create?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem , deceze is right,i just can't,not because of my inability to learn

Comment: Well, `strtotime()` doesn't have a crystal ball they can query for the last database creation date; you'd have to keep track of this in, perhaps, a separate table?

Comment: All this would be much easier (and had better performance) if you had only one database with an additional field for the date in your table.

Comment: @14k: Just to be absolutely sure - is it because you're still running PHP4, because I can't see any other reason why you can't switch

Comment: @Elias,No is not,why the hell i would still have php 4??

Comment: @GeraldSchneider yes it would be,but i have many databases,and i cant add a field for date,i know what you mean,and it is a good idea,but not in my case

Comment: @14k: Because PHP ships with `mysqli` as standard since PHP 5.0, and PDO was included since PHP 5.1, so if you have a technical reason, I struggle to think of any other reason than a _very_ old PHP version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for,doesnt exists.There is not a value like the one you are looking for.All you have to do,is to think,and find some tricks in your show query,to add multiples strtotime() functions,so you can cover each situation will cause you problems.Good luck.

Comment: indeed....anyway i just wanted to know if there is such a syntax.Seems like i have to do it in the hard way.Thanks anyway.